# Jquery display one or multiple file names when file(s) are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display one or multiple file names before a user submits the files, but as of now I can only display one file name rather than multiple file names if a user decides to select multiple files.

Jquery

```
$(function() {
 $('input:file').change(function(){
     var fileName = $(this).val();
     $('.filenames').html('<div class="name">' + fileName + '</div>');
 });
});
```

Comment: use `.append` instead of `.html`

Comment: @Undefined_variable  what is the advantage of append vs html?

Comment: .html replaces the entire content inside the selector while append will append to the list

Comment: @NIMISHAN We edit redundant text like thanks, thanks for the help or help please out of posts rather than in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `for` loop with `this.files.length`

```js
$(function() {
 $('input:file').change(function(){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.files.length ; i++){
      var fileName = this.files[i].name;
      $('.filenames').append('<div class="name">' + fileName + '</div>');
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
<div class="filenames"></div>
```

OR `$.each` with `this.files` <sup>Updated: 08/02/2020</sup>

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:file').on('change' , function(){
    $.each(this.files , (i , v) => {
      var filename = v.name;
      $('.filenames').append('<div class="name">' + filename + '</div>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
<div class="filenames"></div>
```

Comment: I tried your code it's working but gives me an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". fixed it by modifying "<=" in  i <= this.files.length to "<", looks like last index length is out of bounds and this is the reason of the undefined. you may also use "his.files.length - 1"

Comment: Glad it helped @Fadz .. I also updated my answer with `$.each` to avoid the undefined index .. Thanks and Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 4):

Replace below

```
$('.filenames').html('<div class="name">' + fileName + '</div>');
```

to

```
$('.filenames').append('<div class="name">' + fileName + '</div>');
```

`html` replaces the existing element with new one. Where as `append` merges the current content with existing one.